# SVN User Configuration / Is it possible to have a user in SVN be able to update but not commit?

Tags: svn, permissions, commit

Is it possible to have a user in SVN be able to update but not commit?

I want to have someone be able to see code but not be able to commit.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you doing your authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up particular users or groups with just 'read' access. This way, they still need to authenticate to get the code, but they can't commit anything.

@ryanprayogo provides the links to setting these permissions so I won't repeat them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Depending on the SVN server access method (whether you use `http://` or `svn://`, etc), you will need to configure stuff differently.

For Apache/httpd: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz

For svnserve: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- it's called anonymous access.  See [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for more info on how to configure it (example configuration files are [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir.ex-1))